# Team City - Branch Specific Artifact Dependencies

Tags: dependencies, teamcity, build-dependencies

I have a solution which has a number of dependencies on other projects and as such we have our build set up with artifact dependencies to pull binaries in from specific builds of these dependencies.

Now we have a project to upgrade one of these dependencies to a new major version, and so we have created a new branch to work on this. As we are upgrading a dependency in this project, we need this branch - and this branch only - to build against the new dependency version. I can change the dependency configuration for the project, but I do not know how to change it for just one branch. I have searched around and asked colleagues about this but cannot find anything about it. Is it even possible to do this in Team City? Will we need to create a separate project building from the same source in version control?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to achieve without creating a new build configuration which defines a new set of dependencies.